# Searching for data in the database using Hibernate+GWT

Tags: java, database, hibernate, validation, gwt

I am to the topic of Hibernate. I am working no on validation system now. I would like to search the database, whether data entered by the user already exists in it, such as login. How to do it using hibernate?

Comment: Please supply some more information on your framework and structure of code

Comment: I use GWT. On the client side, there is a form, where users can fill inputs. I would like to check correctness of the data, when a user goes to the next field. I would like to invoke validation method in onLostFocus() method, but I think, that this is not essential at this point.

Comment: Okay. And you are passing the data to the server via GWT RPC where hibernate is called within the servlet?

Comment: Yes. I have found this tutorial: http://techblog.maydu.eu/?p=7 Is it worth using?

Answer (score 1):

Please check following link: http://gwt-vl.sourceforge.net/?to=serverDoc

Esspecially the section: *Server side to client side validation* This may help you to validate your form on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know about communication with backend I would recommend (GWT_PLATFORM)[http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/] it's a great framework by Philip Beaudoin and also some highly respected by GWT team and was infect release before GWT MVP . 
 Okay you already have that sorted out then what you will need to work out what combination of UI fields is a unique database entity for example Name and Date of Birth something along these lines. Then before you persist this data you will using your DAO (I am assuming you have a DAO layer) search for that object (you can use JPA QL even with hibernate or Hibernate Criteria) if your search (and user doesnot know about it just a back end process) does not return a result then you can just persist then new information but if it does then it will be upto the business rule weather you show user and error or update the information.